# Localization in Yesod

Tags: haskell, localization, yesod

I use the localization for application from yesod (module Text.Shakespeare.I18N).
Below is example of code

```
data STest = STest
mkMessage "STest" "messages" ("ru")
trMsg msg  = renderMessage STest ["ru"] msg
```

But if I want use several localization at the same time, I try

```
mkMessage "STest" "messages" ("ru")
mkMessage "STest" "messages" ("en")
```

or

```
mkMessage "STest" "messages" ("ru", "en")
```

This decision was an error!
How can i use several localization at the same time?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/internationalization) has an example that should solve your issue exactly, two languages (hebrew, english), and messages that should be displayed.

Also the [documentation](http://haddock.stackage.org/nightly-2016-04-19/shakespeare-2.0.8.1/Text-Shakespeare-I18N.html) is quite clear about this the `mkMessages` function

> `mkMessage`
>
> `:: String`    base name to use for translation type
>   `-> FilePath`  subdirectory which contains the translation files
>   `-> Lang`  default translation language
>   `-> Q [Dec]`    generate translations from translation files
>
> This function will:
>
> look in the supplied subdirectory for files ending in .msg generate a
>   type based on the constructors found create a `RenderMessage` instance

So you are trying to have multiple default languages - which is not possible. Please read the link I have provided to the yesod book - I hope this solves all your problems.